# Como clonar um objeto no javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Estou querendo passar um objeto por parâmetro de uma função, porém não quero que esse objeto seja alterado. Para isso quero passar por parâmetro um clone.

Pois no javascript, pelos testes que fiz, o objeto sempre é passado por referência.

Exemplo:

```
a = {}
b = a;

b.nome = 'Wallace';

console.log(a, b); //Object {nome: "Wallace"} Object {nome: "Wallace"}
```

Veja que os dois objeto foram alterados.

Como fazer essa atribuição de `b` para `a` no javascript, sem manter as referências?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com `Object.create()`:

**Exemplo:**

```js
a = {}
b = Object.create(a);
b.nome = 'Gabriel';
a.nome = 'Wallace';
document.write(JSON.stringify(a), JSON.stringify(b))
```

Comment: Favor usar `document.write` no lugar de `console.log` :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Para visualização fica pessimo, fica [Object][Object]..

Comment: Só dar `JSON.stringify` meu amigo :D

Comment: Gabriel, sabe porque os dados ficam dentro de `__proto__` quando se usa assim?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tenho 100% de certeza, mas acho que é a Herança. se você criar um item no objeto a você verá que o b ira herdar ele, o a não tera ___proto___ mas o b terá

Comment: Este método não é a melhor alternativa.

Comment: @devgaspa Poderia elaborar uma resposta  fazendo a comparação ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer a clonagem através do método `$.extend` do jQuery.

Veja:

```js
a = {}

b = $.extend({}, a);

b.nome = 'Teste';


document.write(JSON.stringify(a), JSON.stringify(b))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```