# Por que ao usar Object.create criar-se a propriedade __proto__?

Tags: javascript

Acabei de fazer essa pergunta
[Como clonar um objeto no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100569/como-clonar-um-objeto-no-javascript)

E me surgiu uma outra dúvida. Quando eu crio um objeto a partir de outro com `Object.create` é adicionado ao novo objeto o atributo `__proto__` contendo o conteúdo o objeto passado por argumento de `create`.

Assim:

```js
function writeObject(obj)
{
    document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

a = {nome: 'wallace'}

b = Object.create(a);

writeObject(a);
writeObject(b);
writeObject(b.__proto__);
```

O que significa esse `__proto__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `__proto__` é o protótipo do objeto (ao contrário do `.prototype` de uma função, que não é protótipo dela, e sim do objeto que ela cria quando invocada como construtora).

Só que `__proto__` era uma propriedade **não-padrão** até pouco tempo atrás (mesmo que disponível em todas as implementações que eu conheço), e por isso não deve ser usada. Nada garante que ela exista na sua implementação (pense no futuro!). O fato é que no JavaScript, até ES5, não existe como alterar o protótipo de um objeto existente sem usar `__proto__`. É pra isso que ele serve, e deve ser usado com muita cautela por questões de performance.

Em ES6 (ECMA-2015 em diante), o `__proto__` foi incluído na especificação, para fins de compatibilidade, mas já veio marcado como obsoleto (*deprecated*), em favor de `Object.setPrototypeOf` e `Object.getPrototypeOf`. Mas mesmo com a padronização, alterar o protótipo *on-the-fly* continua sendo contraindicado por questões de performance.

Comment: ela é uma getter function que só e criada quando é feita uma herança? vi na documentação que deveria utilizar Object.getPrototypeOf invés do `___proto___`  no caso é claro de acessar os valores...

Comment: Não sei como é implementado pelos motores, mas ele se comporta como getter e setter. Em ES5 você pode usar `Object.getPrototypeOf` para a função de getter, mas para o setter não tem alternativa.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf mas é claro apenas em ES6

Comment: Legal, não tinha certeza se esse método tinha passado dos *drafts* para a versão final, ainda bem que sim.

Comment: No [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Specifications) também fala que a propriedade `__proto__` é padronizada do ES6.0 até o ES7.

Comment: @Matheus Dei uma atualizada na resposta, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro parâmetro desse método `Object.create` é exatamente o objeto que deve ser o protótipo para a criação do novo objeto. Daí que esse parâmtro seja chamado de `proto` (ver [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)) e acessível via `__proto__`, ou seja é a referência do Objeto passado como argumento ao `Object.create` para criar o novo objeto.

```
var original = {};
var novo = Object.create(original);

console.log(original == novo); // false
console.log(original == novo.__proto__); // true
```