# Qual a necessidade de __proto__?

Tags: javascript

Qual a necessidade de `"__proto__"` em um objeto? Acabei de fazer uns testes e percebi que `"__proto__"` não é uma propriedade, mas pode ser indexado.

Quando eu defino uma propriedade em x objeto, essa propriedade também fica disponível em `"__proto__"`, mas quando eu faço o vice-versa a propriedade não fica disponível em x objeto.

`"__proto__"` parece similiar à `Object` porque tem algumas propriedades com o mesmo nome

[image: obj#__proto__]

O objeto global parece ter `"__proto__"` de forma diferente

[image: window#__proto__]

Sendo assim, o que `"__proto__"` faz de tão especial em JavaScript? As diferenças entre #__proto__ e Function#prototype fazem sentido, mas #__proto__ em sí não tem sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__proto__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn342818(v=vs.94).aspx) contém uma referência para o protótipo interno do objeto especificado. Pode ser usada para definir o protótipo para um objeto.

O objeto ou função herda todos os métodos e propriedades de novo protótipo, juntamente com todos os métodos e propriedades na cadeia de protótipo do novo protótipo.Um objeto pode ter apenas um único protótipo (não incluindo protótipos herdados na cadeia de protótipo), para que quando você chamar a propriedade de `__proto__`, você substitua o protótipo anterior.

Achei essa imagem interessante, retirei dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249437/5327226) do stackoverflow em inglês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já existem repostas explicando teoria que podem ser úteis:

- [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/51124)
- [O que é Protótipo Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/51124)
- [Por que ao usar Object.create criar-se a propriedade `__proto__`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100576/51124)